# Could not load file or assembly 'ParserBuilder'

Tags: c#, exception, console, class-library

When I run my .exe file its showing below mentioned error in console.
so any idea how to solve it.`ParserBuilder` is my class Library.

Here is the error :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ParserBuilder', Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=... or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

Repair your Visual Studio.
Download file from here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8XrlgnW-cfISXd1Q0VQb0gtNk0/edit

and place it here: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web

Enjoy !

Comment: How to use it its a dll right i am able download some delete file from the link you have given

Comment: Either do a fresh install or browse to the directory where you have already installed it.